# Сбой при входе в режим прерывания

Tags: c#, wpf

Вылезает при компиляции проекта. И из проекта исчезли все ссылки на форму. Подскажите пожалуйста, из-за чего это может быть и как это исправить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в этом окне, которое вы приводите, разве не ясно написано?

Comment: Проблема в том, что все строилось. А потом я решил продолжить делать это приложение и начало возникать вот это. И почему то исчезли ссылки на форму (кнопки и прочие элементы) Это уже не первый раз такое. Возможно в этот раз то же поможет собрать проект заново (взять копировать код и создать новую форму), но если честно я уже устал каждый раз это делать. По этому и решил спросить из-за чего эта ошибка возникает и почему исчезают ссылки на форму.

Comment: А вы расскажите, как вы копировали файлы в проект, проводником что-ли копировали? Вот в окне ясно говорится, что `MainWindow.xaml.cs` не является частью проекта, такое может быть если испорчен файл `ИмяПроекта.csproj` или `MainWindow.xaml.cs` удален. Где-то шаловливые ручки что-то удалили или не туда скопировали.

Comment: Да нет все лежит в проекте. В папочке. Ничего не удалялось.

Comment: Я сейчас заново переделал проект и вылезла та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Создайте проект пустой, попробуйте скомпилировать и запустить. Получается?

Comment: Нет, делал только что.

Comment: А ругается на что?

Comment: В том и проблема, что ни на что. Он прогоняет проект и вылезает вот эта штука.

Comment: У меня догадки закончились. А вы пробовали создать пустой проект любого другого типа и его запустить? Работает?

Comment: Да работают. Вот можете попробовать сами у себя. http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread2144366.html#post11887251

Comment: Я вас просил проверить построение и запуск пустого проекта, а вы мне показываете код, который в данном случае не пришей кобыле хвост. Зачем мне проверять этот код? В нем нет ничего, что относилось бы к теме?!

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, что вы от меня хотите. Я создал новый проект и перегнал в кнопки туда. Снова вылезла эта ошибка. Другие проекты запускаются правильно. В том проекте, что я вам скинул и возникает ошибка. (в котором как раз и исчезли ссылки на форму.

Comment: Версия студии? В 2017й периодически всплывает косяк с тем, что проект не дочитывается при открытии, и часть файлов во вложенных папках в обозревателе солюшена видна, но вроде как не подключена, помогает создание в проблемной папке нового класса (и удаление) после чего папка перечитыется и дальше работает все без проблем, может и тут что-то похожее на косячили...